# How do I count instances of values in columns by individual column using only SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Assume the following -
I am recording (in a single table) the elapsed duration in complete days of a number of business processes.
The duration can range from 1 day to 50 days.
Assume there are twenty different process types being monitored and within each process type an individual process instance can have a duration anywhere between the minimum and maximum duration range (1 - 50).

For example -

Table 1 Column 1 would list the recorded duration values for Process 1 (example values - 23,5,17,41,...).

Table 1 Column 2 would list the recorded duration values for Process 2.

Table 1 Column 3 would list the recorded duration values for Process 3...
and so on.

Required -

I want to take this data and, in a second table, for each process type count how many times a particular duration occurs.

For example -

Table 2 Column 1 would list (in ascending order) the possible duration values (1 to 50).

Subsequent Table 2 columns will represent (for each of these values in Column 1) a count of how often each has occurred for each process type (one column per process type).

So, for example, in Process 1 the duration of 35 days might occur 46 times, whereas in Process 2 it might occur 23 times.

Hope this makes sense!

Is this even possible in SQL Server and if so how do I accomplish this?
Preferably, this should take as few steps as possible with as little interaction from the user as possible - if it could be done!
Also, what happens if, in future, I have to monitor more processes?

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response guys! Mellamokb - works exactly as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind having to manually change the query whenever the number of process types changes, this should do it (example given for 4 process types):

```
;With Sequence([Days]) as
(
    Select 1 as [Days]
        union all
    Select [Days] + 1
        from Sequence
        where [Days] < 50
)
select
  S.[Days]
  ,Count(case when P.[P1]=S.[Days] then 1 end) AS [P1Count]
  ,Count(case when P.[P2]=S.[Days] then 1 end) AS [P2Count]
  ,Count(case when P.[P3]=S.[Days] then 1 end) AS [P3Count]
  ,Count(case when P.[P4]=S.[Days] then 1 end) AS [P4Count]
from Sequence S, ProcessDuration P
group by S.[Days]
```

The `Sequence` cte at the top generates the numbers 1 to 50.  Then the output uses `Count` with a `case` statement to count matches for each process type to the number of days.  The output is a grid with `1-50` along the left side, and the count for each process type in the successive columns.

You'll need to modify the table/column names to be relevant for your particular schema.

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b51da/5

Comment: Thank you! (and apologies for the tardy response...).